# Tangent space groups of compact manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

Reading a review, I have come across this sentence

> ...of the $SO(D)$ tangent space group of the manifold $K$

after some pages I have found

> ...for the case of a $D$-dimensional compact manifolds $K$, the tangent space-group is $G_T=SO(1,3+D)$

In both sentences $D$ is the dimensionality of the compact manifold.

I have two main questions:

1)What is a "tangent space-group"

2)is it $SO(D)$ or $SO(1,3+D)$? (Because there must be is a typo in one of the sentences I have cited). And in either case, why is it $SO(D)$ or $SO(1,3+D)$?

Answer (score 0):

You should be more precise.

$SO(D)$  usually denotes the special orthogonal group in dimension $D$, while
$SO(1,3+D)$ means the group of (orientation preserving) transformations of $\mathbb R^{4+D}$ that preserve the standard bilinear form with signature $(1,3+D)$

the word "tangent space group" may refer to the structure group of the tangent space. This is probably the case if one study metric strucutres, when changes of coordinates are required to preserve some given bilinear form (Euclidean in the $SO(n)$ case, and Minkowsky-type in the case $SO(1,3+D)$)

Comment: what is the structure group of the tangent space?

Comment: the tangent space is a special case of vector bundle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_the_structure_group_of_a_bundle

Comment: see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_group#Structure_groups_and_transition_functions

Comment: I am afraid those links exceed my level of mathematical knowledge, thanks anyway for the info